# How many elements of order 2 are in the Group D10 x D8?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

Dihedral groups really confuse me. What are the elements of D10 and D8? I need to know these in order to find the elements in D10 x D8. Then maybe I can figure out the order of those elements. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the first part kind of depends on the description of the dihedral group that you're working with, but for the latter: suppose $g \in D_{10}$ has order two, and $h \in D_{8}$ does too. then $(g, h) (g, h) = (gg, hh) = (e, e)$ (the identity element). this isn't a statement about the dihedral group specifically — can you see what happens for a general group when $h$ has order three? and what about when they have orders $m$ and $n$ respectively?

Comment: I think you need to show some of your own work.  Anyway, the answer is 35.

Comment: @SteveD: Do you think, in this problem, using the presentations of the group $D_{10}\times D_8$ and then finding the way of enumerating those elements is easier than using the definition of the direct product as in the first comment above?

Comment: @BabakS.: The first comment is definitely the way to go, but there is more to do than just multiplying two numbers.

Comment: @exitingcorpse: Thank you! I understand how the definition of the direct product should be used, but I don't know how to find the order of an element in D10, or what the elements of D10 even look like?

Comment: @exitingcorpse: Also, my text defines Dihedral groups as D2n, where n is any positive integer. So I think that means that in D10, n is 5 meaning that I'm looking at a 5 sided figure. D10 has 10 elements.

Comment: The dihedral group $D_{2n}$ can be thought of as the symmetries of an $n$-sided regular polygon.  Thus we can decompose $D_{2n}$ thusly: half of it is a cyclic group of order $n$, corresponding to rotations; the other half consists of all the reflections - it does not form a subgroup, but every reflection has order two.  Thus half of $D_{2n}$ is a cyclic group of order $n$, and the other half is order-two elements ($n$ of them).

Comment: @SteveD: Thank you for the explanation. I think I understand now. But I'm getting 36 elements with order 2, not 35. Please correct me if some of my thinking is wrong. In D10 there are 6 elements of order 2 (the 5 reflections and rotation R0). In D8 there are 6 elements of order 2 (the 4 reflections and 2 rotations R0 and R180). So if I use the direct product mentioned in the first comment I get 36 elements of order 2 in D10 x D8. Am I missing something?

Comment: $D_{10}$ has $5$ elements of order $2$ (not $6$), and $D_8$ also has $5$ elements of order $2$ (not $6$). So the total is $5+5+5 \times 5=35$. I think perhaps you were counting the number of elements $g$ satisfying $g^2=1$. There are indeed $36$ of those, but one of them is the identity, which has order $1$, not $2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Yes, I was counting the identity! I totally see why the answer is 35 now and can justify my answer. Thank you all SO much!

Comment: Cindy, please post your work as an answer to your own question.  Then people can check to make sure it is correct, and the question won't remain unanswered.